# Multilingual Snap-ins Chat in Lightning Community

Tags: liveagent, napili, community-builder, lightning-community, translation-workbench

We recently internationalized our napili template lightning community using translation workbench and community languages. It's been mostly very smooth but we've hit a snag with our Live Agent support.

We added a Snap Ins Chat component via community builder and this translates nicely for each locale we have in our community. However, it can only be associated with one Snap-Ins Chat deployment, which can only be associated with one Chat Button, which can only be associated with one language. To put this in real life terms, we cannot route incoming chats to certain users based on language; moreover we can't even tell live agents beforehand what language a chat is going to be in.

Is there an accepted way to handle this? I'm weighing a few different hacks and none of them seem all that appealing:

- Add one snap ins chat component per language, and use some CSS tricks to hide the unwanted ones via :lang (not sure if this even works because each snap-ins chat seems to display in the current language automatically)
- Add one page variation per locale (this would be audience-driven and thus wouldn't work for unauthenticated users)

Comment: Hello! I am facing this exact issue.  Were you able to come up with a solution?